# Passing User Credentials between Vue-Router Components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-props

I'm new in front-end development and learning Vue 3. I'm currently working on a user Login and Registration pages and I have a problem that I don't know how to solve properly.

The application has a Login page (with Email and Password fields) and a Registration page (with Email, Name, Password and Repeat password fields). Everywhere APIs are connected that check user data when clicking on the Submit button.

Now I have the following task: if the user enters an Email address that has already been registered before, then a pop-up window appears, which says: "Email is already in use. ***Sing Up*** to continue."

If the user clicks on ***Sing Up***, then he should be routed to the Login page, in which the data that he just entered on the registration page will be automatically entered into the Email and Password fields.

For routing, I use Vue Router. I have read in the documentation that it is possible to pass props between components, however I am not sure if this is the safest and most correct method.

PS I can't use global state managers like Pinia or Vuex (the team I work for told me to not using them).

Thanks for your help and attention!

I tried using props method but I got problems during compilation

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck.
So leave a question, show us your code, what did you try and your research:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: " I can't use global state managers" - it's all in the docs, it's unnecessary to use state management lib to have global state https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html#simple-state-management-with-reactivity-api

Comment: @EstusFlask thank You for comment! Is this optimal way to share personal data between components? Which method is better: using props or global state?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's personal in this case. It totally depends on your case. If it's awkward to do this through props (in this case it is) then it's global state.

Comment: @EstusFlask I'm also interested in the implementation of automatic deletion of this data after login. Does this data need to be cleared somehow after success login? It turns out that you need to wrap it all up in some kind of function or hook?

Comment: Yes, makes sense to clear the credentials from the store after the redirect to login page. In the snippet in the link above, you can import `store` directly, composable function like `useStore` is generally not needed here, can be useful for some edge cases

Answer (score 0):

What kinda problem are you facing ? you need to insert the part of code at least or screenshot your problem.
If you want to pass data, you just add **props** in your route file, example :

```
{ 
 path: "/example",
 name: "example",
 props: true,
}
```

And for sending a data, you need to pass data to **params**.
Example for option API:

```
this.$router.push('example', {
 params: {email:email, pass:pass};
})
```

Example for composition API:

```
router.push({
 name: 'example',
 params: {email:email, pass:pass},
})
```

Dont forget to import router. Now you just add **props variable**:

```
props: ['email', 'pass']
//or composition API
const props =  defineProps({
  email: String, pass:String
})
const { email, pass } = toRefs(props)
```